# How/can do you connect VS2010 to Codeplex's TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, codeplex

I've gone to Team-->Connect and tried to enter the details for the TFS on the CddePlex site:

https://tfs05.codeplex.com

Then it asks for the user name and password - which I assume is something like

mycodeplexusername@codeplex.com + my codeplex password.

But is doesn't let me sign in?

What assumption is making an ass of me?

Comment: I'm thinking now that I have to have actually joined a project as a devloper to be granted permission - is that right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your username is probably

```
snd\username_cp
```

Replace username with your username

Answer (score 6):

I blogged about this subject using vs2010 
http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/how-to-use-team-explorer-with-codeplex/

Answer (score 3):

brickner's answer is correct. (snd\username_cp)

You can see the instructions to connect by clicking on the project's **Source Code** tab. Then on the right, click on the appropriate link under "**Source Control Setup**". This includes instructions for Visual Studio Team Explorer, Subversion and various other source control clients.

Comment: Where did 'snd' come from? And i followed the links in the Source Control Setup - was i not seeing something because i'm not a project member?

Comment: yes if you are not a project member it doesn't show you login details. I use TortoiseSVN to pull the latest code down for CodePlex projects.

Answer (score -1):

This worked !

Register here to obtain acccount
https://inventory.codeplex.com/site/register

Then concatente your usernme like so in the visual studio sign in

snd\username_cp